# GDebi help please

Tags: gdebi

I have installed this to deal with a `.deb` file.

In GDebi it takes me through to the file location, on Desktop. I highlight it and then nothing happens. GDebi remains empty and I remain at a loss.

PH

Comment: What happens if you right-click the `.deb` file and open with another... -> GDebi? If it doesn't work the file is corrupt, download it again.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand. If I RC it opens in to 4 folders. How does that help instal please??

Comment: Right-click > **Open with** > select GDebi...

Comment: Ok so I did the DL again and now  (hollow chuckle) am getting the message: iscan-gt-f720-bundle-1.0.1.x86.deb.tar.gz is not a Debian package. Also the software installer says it cannot instal it so what is the next move please?

Comment: It's a compressed file. Of course it **isn't** a `.deb`, cannot be installed with GDebi and it makes you question nonsensical (you specifically asked about a `. deb`file). Perhaps you should describe *what* you want to do instead, what are you trying to install...

Comment: I am trying to install the drivers for an epson perfection v300 scanner and the epson site gives that bundle as the required driver.

Comment: Yes, but you download the source code. Here are the debs: http://support.epson.net/linux/en/iscan.php?model=gt-f720&version=1.0.1

Comment: Then you can install using Gdebi like in this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/960222/692175

Comment: That is precisely what I downloaded. The 32 link  at the top.

Comment: Unfortunately no debs due to a mistake by whoever is managing the website. You'll have to install it according to the instructions. 1. Double-click  the `.tar.gz` and extract it to your user area. 2. Open "readme" and follow instructions starting with cd (because you already extracted the file contents).

Comment: Could you please [edit] your post, when you want to clarify something or add information? It’s best to have everything relevant in one place. Additionally, comments may be deleted for various reasons. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

From what I understood while reading the comments, you want to install **Epson Perfection v300** scanner drivers.

### Step 1:

Download the correct [driver](http://support.epson.net/linux/en/iscan.php?model=gt-f720&version=1.0.1) depending on your PC Architecture (32-64 bit) and Distribution.

### Step 2:

Extract the `tar.gz` file you just downloaded by <kbd>Right Click</kbd> on it and <kbd>Left Click</kbd> on **Extract Here** from the dropdown menu (Ubuntu). If you use a different Distribution, search on Google "How to extract files on X", replacing 'X' with your Distribution name.

### Step 3:

You will see a file called `install.sh`. <kbd>Right Click</kbd> on the space where the install.sh file is (not on the file) and choose **Open in Terminal** (Ubuntu).

[image]
 Then, write the following command:

```
./install.sh
```

Or, open a terminal and type `sudo /path/to/install.sh`, replacing "/path/to" with your path, where the `install.sh` is saved.

This will install all the needed `.deb` packages automatically.

Comment: Excellent information precisely what I needed. Many many thanks for taking the time.

Comment: If I solved your question, marking the post as answer will also help other people. Glad I helped.

Comment: Although this helped OP it doesn't actually answer the question because OP only mentions the underlying issue in the comments.

Comment: It looks OK anyway.

Comment: I am happy to mark this as answered if someone can tell me how please.

Comment: Next to my answer, you'll see a check mark under the Upvote/Downvote arrows (^V). Click it.